# Transparent control over drew shape

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I'm new for create user control, and in my first usercontrol i used from picturebox and label ,
picturebox for draw a shape and label for show text over that shape.
i was set picturebox parent for label, and label backcolor to transparent also if don't have any text label set to visible = false

now i have a problem, when label is visible, i can't see picturebox correctly.

[image]

how can i solve this problem ?

also paint event on user control not work

```
    private void Ucontrol_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (RightToLeft)
        {
            lblTxt.RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.Yes;
        }
        else
        {
            lblTxt.RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.No;
        }

        lblTxt.ForeColor = FontColor;
        lblTxt.Text = Txt;
        if (Question)
        {
            BorderColor = Color.DarkBlue;
            BackColor = Color.FromArgb(75, 163, 234);
            CreateQuestion(BorderColor, BackColor);
        }
        else
        {
            BorderColor = Color.DarkGreen;
            BackColor = Color.FromArgb(59, 226, 75);
            CreateAnswer(BorderColor, BackColor);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have accepted a wrong answer. All you need to add to your code was one line to add the label to the picturebox's controls collection and one to set its location. Pictubreboxes don't help with that in the as containers do but they work just as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Forms controls don't have really a transpartent background, they copy it's parent content.

Also, a PictureBox can't be parent of another control as they aren't container.

Then, instead of using a picturebox just set the usercontrol background image and put the label on it, the transparency should work.

Here is a working example manually drawing the control content:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Label lbl = new Label();
        lbl.Location = new Point(10, 10);
        lbl.Width = 150;
        lbl.Height = 150;
        lbl.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        lbl.Text = @"asdfasdfasdfasdf\r\nasdfasdfasdf\r\n\r\nasdfasdfasdf";

        lbl.Visible = true;

        this.Controls.Add(lbl);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, new Rectangle(10, 10, 100, 100));
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Yellow, new Rectangle(10, 10, 100, 100));
    }
}
```

Comment: how can i use Graphics as BackgroundImage ?

Comment: if you're drawing directly, instead of drawing to the picturebox draw to the usercontrol, use the Paint event.

Comment: It should unless you're using a very old framework, in that case you need to do a SetStyle to it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wk5b13s4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I'm on.net 4.5 ! user control support transparent and label support but i cant see shape under label !

Comment: Stupid question, did you set the backgroundcolor of the label to Transparent? I'm testing it in a control and works without problems

Comment: Thanks, But can you please check this pic : http://i.stack.imgur.com/AQBxF.png   i don't know why ! do you have any idea ?

Comment: Ehm... it looks like you're not painting explicitly the area of the label, post your CreateQuestion code

Comment: Thanks, with your code I found my problem ! you use `e.Graphics` but i use from this : `Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();`

Comment: Glad you found it :D

Comment: _Also, a PictureBox can't be parent of another control as they aren't container._ Yes it can! However you need to code it: Llabel1.Parent = PictureBox

Comment: *Also, a PictureBox can't be parent of another control at design time as they aren't container.* :P

Comment: While the remark true this still is a wrong answer. Giving up on PictureBox for a totally false reason may not matter in this case, but it is simply wrong advice. PBs do a lot more than one would want to lose. The question was not about design time but why the label didn't get nested at all.

Comment: no, the question was why it wasn't rendering the background, and it was because the picturebox was not the parent of the control, and in the designer you can't set it, and also, using a non-container control as parent is always a really bad idea, and finally the user was just using the Graphics object to draw in the PictureBox so it was totally unnecessary.